# what's the best way to update state using set state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

I have tried to update a state of an array but it keep failing, and finally decided to do it using the assignment operator which I know it's not good. for now it is working fine but I would like to use a setState instead

Current code

```
this.state.Days[selectedDay].selected = this.state.Days[selectedDay].selected == true ?  false : true
```

I tried to do this but it did not work

```
this.setstate{Days[selectedDay]: {selected: (this.state.Days[selectedDay].selected: == true ?  false : true) } }
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can setState

```
state={
 selected:false
}
```

function code

```
handleSelect=item=>{
 this.setState({selected: item})
}
```

html code like this

```
<div onClick={()=>this.handleSelec(true)}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Days = this.state.Days;
Days[selectedDay].selected = ! Days[selectedDay].selected;
this.setState({Days});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.